# Should I say "where does" or "where did"?

Tags: tense

Which is more appropriate to say?

> Where does Yuji buy the guitar?

or

> Where did Yuji buy the guitar?

Answer (score 8):

If the guitar was bought in the past, the correct question is

> Where did Yuji buy the guitar?

If the purchasing has not happened when the question is asked then it would be:

> Where is Yuji buying the guitar?

If instead of a (probably) one-off purchase of a guitar, the question was refering to a purchase that is made frequently (eg apples), the question would be:

> Where does Yuji buy his/her apples?

Answer (score 0):

> [Where **did** Yuji **buy** the guitar?]

*means* that Yuji **did something in the past**. You should use it when you knew Yuji bought it (e.g. yesterday).

> [Where **does** Yuji **buy** the guitar?]

is *not appropriate*. It is because present tense should be used when you want to express something happen in the daily routine, habitual action or general truth.

NB: A question (about buying something) **won't appear** if you do not know anything about it.